# Does minifying python code makes it faster?

Tags: python

I saw those libraries for python code minification :

https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/

https://mnfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Would minifying python code make it run faster ?

Comment: Insomuch as there are less bytes to read from the disk before interpretation, sure.

Comment: No, it does not. CPython is compiled to bytecode, which is what is actually executed by the Python runtime interpreter.

Comment: These tools are problems pretending to be solutions.

Comment: It doesn't make code faster in general, it makes the code obfuscated (security by hiding) and small enough to be deployed in embedded systems where memory matters.

Comment: The only real world case where minification might be useful is if file size is a design concern, but it is unlikely you are developing in a storage restrictive environment using python in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Practically yes, even if you remove just one character, it will run faster, but it just won't be noticeable. I would rather have a ton of comments explaining the code rather than wanting it to be 0.00000001 seconds faster. On the other side, Python isn't made for speed, I mean, It's quite fast comparing to some other languages but it just isn't made with that purpose in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Minification of the python code is a game for 1 microsecond.

Pypy could speed up you program up to ~10 times.